# How to attach a debugger dynamically to a specific process

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am building an internal development tool to manage different processes commonly used in our development environment. The tool shows the list of the monitored processes, indicating their running state and allows to start or stop each process.

I'd like to add the functionality of attaching a debugger to a monitored process from my tool instead of going in *Debug* -> *Attach to process* in Visual Studio and finding the process.

My goal is to have something like `Debugger.Launch()` that would show a list of the available Visual Studio. I can't use `Debugger.Launch()`, because it launches the debugger on the process that makes the call. I would need something like `Debugger.Launch(processId)`.

How do I achieve this functionality?

A solution could be to implement a command in each monitored process to call `Debugger.Launch()` when the command is received from the monitoring tool, but I would prefer something that does not require to modify the code of the monitored processes.

Side question:

When using `Debugger.Launch()`, instances of Visual Studio that already have a debugger attached are not listed. Visual Studio is not limited to one attached debugger, you can attach on multiple process when using *Debug* → *Attach to process*.

How do I bypass this limitation when using `Debugger.Launch()` or an alternative?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A coworker ended up with a solution using DTE, and I posted the code on PasteBin.

The methods of interest are `AttachVisualStudioToProcess` and `TryGetVsInstance`

[Source Code](http://pastebin.com/KKyBpWQW)

```
public static void AttachVisualStudioToProcess(Process visualStudioProcess, Process applicationProcess)
{
    _DTE visualStudioInstance;

    if (TryGetVsInstance(visualStudioProcess.Id, out visualStudioInstance))
    {
        //Find the process you want the Visual Studio instance to attach to...
        DTEProcess processToAttachTo = visualStudioInstance.Debugger.LocalProcesses.Cast<DTEProcess>().FirstOrDefault(process => process.ProcessID == applicationProcess.Id);

        // Attach to the process.
        if (processToAttachTo != null)
        {
            processToAttachTo.Attach();

            ShowWindow((int)visualStudioProcess.MainWindowHandle, 3);
            SetForegroundWindow(visualStudioProcess.MainWindowHandle);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Visual Studio process cannot find specified application '" + applicationProcess.Id + "'");
        }
    }
}

private static bool TryGetVsInstance(int processId, out _DTE instance)
{
    IntPtr numFetched = IntPtr.Zero;
    IRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable;
    IEnumMoniker monikerEnumerator;
    IMoniker[] monikers = new IMoniker[1];

    GetRunningObjectTable(0, out runningObjectTable);
    runningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out monikerEnumerator);
    monikerEnumerator.Reset();

    while (monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, numFetched) == 0)
    {
        IBindCtx ctx;
        CreateBindCtx(0, out ctx);

        string runningObjectName;
        monikers[0].GetDisplayName(ctx, null, out runningObjectName);

        object runningObjectVal;
        runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikers[0], out runningObjectVal);

        if (runningObjectVal is _DTE && runningObjectName.StartsWith("!VisualStudio"))
        {
            int currentProcessId = int.Parse(runningObjectName.Split(':')[1]);

            if (currentProcessId == processId)
            {
                instance = (_DTE)runningObjectVal;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    instance = null;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you make a custom VS plugin for this?  Or how did you "wire it up"?  I have a similar need.  I'm staring with your code here, but looking for how you wired it up in your end solution.  Thanks.

Comment: We did not make a VS plugin, we used that code in a custom tool that is monitoring our product processes.

Comment: I'm using this code but I can't figure out how to tell VS to attach to managed code. The Attach to process dialogue box asks "Attach to:" where you can select Managed code rather than auto detect. This needs to be set when debugging IISExpress processes. Any idea how to select that in code?

Comment: Auto-detect should work for IISExpress process, but if you really need to specify the engine, you can use Process2.Attach2, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.process2.attach2(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: To be noted: `TryGetVsInstance` will not return the `DTE` object of an instance of Visual Studio which was not started as an administrator, if the calling script is called from a process with elevated rights.

Answer (score 12):

WinDbg does the chain debugging for native code by default. If you want to launch another instance of Visual Studio, check [Launch the Debugger Automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed.aspx) on MSDN:

To automate the existing debugger, use Marshal.GetActiveObject to get the current EnvDTE.Debugger then let it attach to the process you just created.

> Sometimes, you may need to debug the startup code for an application that is launched by another process. Examples include services and custom setup actions. In these scenarios, you can have the debugger launch and automatically attach when your application starts.
>
> **To setup an application to launch the debugger automatically**
>
> 1. Start the Registry Editor (regedit).
> 2. In the Registry Editor, open the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE folder.
> 3. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\currentversion\image file execution options.
> 4. In the **Image File Execution Options** folder, locate the name of the application you want to debug, such as myapp.exe. If you cannot find the application you want to debug:
>
>    a. Right-click the **Image File Execution Options** folder, and on the shortcut menu, click **New Key**.
>
>    b. Right-click the new key, and on the shortcut menu, click **Rename**.
>
>    c. Edit the key name to the name of your application; myapp.exe, in this example.
> 5. Right-click the *myapp.exe* folder, and on the shortcut menu, click **New String Value**.
> 6. Right-click the new string value, and on the shortcut menu, click **Rename**.
> 7. Change the name to `debugger`.
> 8. Right-click the new string value, and on the shortcut menu, click **Modify**.
>      The **Edit String** dialog box appears.
> 9. In the **Value data** box, type **vsjitdebugger.exe**.
> 10. Click **OK**.
> 11. From the **Registry** menu, click **Exit**.
> 12. The directory containing vsjitdebugger.exe must be in your system path. To add it to the system path, follow these steps:
>
>     a. Open the **Control Panel** in Classic view, and double-click **System**.
>
>     b. Click **Advanced System Settings**.
>
>     c. In **System Properties**, click the **Advanced** tab.
>
>     d. On the **Advanced** tab, click **Environment Variables**.
>
>     e. In the **Environment Variables** dialog box, under **System variables**, select Path, then click the **Edit** button.
>
>     f. In the **Edit System Variable** dialog box, add the directory to the **Variable value** box. Use a semicolon to separate it from other entries in the list.
>
>     g. Click **OK** to close the **Edit System Variable** dialog box.
>
>     h. Click **OK** to close the **Environment Variables** dialog box.
>
>     i. Click **OK** to close the **System Properties** dialog box.
>
> Now, use any method to start your application. Visual Studio will start and load the application.

Comment: The link you provided indicate how to start a process with the debugger attached. I want to attach the debugger on a process when it is already running.

After reading the article I checked the documentation about vsjitdebugger and what I exactly what I needed: vsjitdebugger -p ProcessId. Thanks for pointing me into that direction.

Any idea how to attach to a visual studio that is in debugging mode? The list of Visual Studio shown in "Visual Studio Just-in-time debugger" does not display them.

Comment: What do you mean? attach a debugger to Visual Studio that is debugging something else? What is that good for?

Comment: I mean to debug multiple process using only one visual studio instance. It is possible to do it from "Debug -> Attach to process", but the JIT Debugger dialog doesn't shows instances of Visual Studio that are in debugging mode.

Comment: In my case, this would be useful because the monitored processes share a common visual studio solution. This solution is pretty big and consume alot of memory, so using only one instance to debug multiple process saves alot of memory.

Comment: Then you probably need a Visual Studio Extension to automate that.

Comment: @SelflessCoder I have this exact same problem, what was your solution in the end? Did you try VS automation or come up with some other workaround?

Comment: @Matt Howells I updated the question with a solution that a coworker found.

Comment: I'll post an answer on my own question then

Answer (score 6):

Here is some information about how you can programmatically attach the debugger to multiple processes:

- [Attach to locally running processes](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2003/02/09/2076.aspx)
- [Attach to remotely running processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272439/visual-studio-remote-debugging-extensibility)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.