# Visual Studio attach to managed process programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, managed, envdte

I'm trying to programmatically attach to an IISExpress process for debugging. When using the Visual Studio attach to process window I have to select Managed Code as the type to attach to. If auto detect is selected instead, VS tries to debug IISExpress as an x86/native application which does not work.

The following code (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626458/how-to-attach-a-debugger-dynamically-to-a-specific-process/7996376#7996376)) using DTE attaches the debugger but does not appear to attach it as managed code.

```
public static void AttachVisualStudioToProcess(Process visualStudioProcess, Process applicationProcess)
{
    _DTE visualStudioInstance;

    if (TryGetVsInstance(visualStudioProcess.Id, out visualStudioInstance))
    {
        //Find the process you want the VS instance to attach to...
        DTEProcess processToAttachTo = visualStudioInstance.Debugger.LocalProcesses.Cast<DTEProcess>().FirstOrDefault(process => process.ProcessID == applicationProcess.Id);

        //Attach to the process.
        if (processToAttachTo != null)
        {
            processToAttachTo.Attach();

            ShowWindow((int)visualStudioProcess.MainWindowHandle, 3);
            SetForegroundWindow(visualStudioProcess.MainWindowHandle);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Visual Studio process cannot find specified application '" + applicationProcess.Id + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps the DTE library is incapable of suggesting that the debugger should attach to managed code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [Process2.Attach2() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte80.process2.attach2.aspx) instead, available since VS2005.  It takes a debugger engine argument that specifies the kind of debugger you want to use.

Sample code [is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimgries/archive/2005/11/30/498264.aspx).

Comment: Hans, you are a legend. This works perfectly! I will post the slightly modified code in another answer.

Comment: The code could be simplified by passing the string argument `"native"` directly into the `attach2` method. Like described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.process2.attach2.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Working code taken and modified from Hans' answer:

```
    public static void AttachVisualStudioToProcess(Process visualStudioProcess, Process applicationProcess)
    {
        _DTE visualStudioInstance;

        if (TryGetVsInstance(visualStudioProcess.Id, out visualStudioInstance))
        {

            EnvDTE100.Debugger5 dbg5 = (EnvDTE100.Debugger5)visualStudioInstance.Debugger;
            EnvDTE80.Transport trans = dbg5.Transports.Item("Default");
            EnvDTE80.Engine dbgeng;
            dbgeng = trans.Engines.Item("Managed (v4.5, v4.0)");
            var proc2 = (EnvDTE80.Process2)dbg5.GetProcesses(trans, "WIN-86CEJEGQCPD").Item("iisexpress.exe");
            proc2.Attach2(dbgeng);


        }
    }
```

I added references to EnvDTE100, EnvDTE90, EnvDTE90a and EnvDTE80 but I suspect if you just stick to debugger2 rather than debugger5 you would only need EnvDTE80.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your code.

```
public static void Attach(DTE2 dte)
        {
            var processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses;
            foreach (var proc in processes.Cast<EnvDTE.Process>().Where(proc => proc.Name.IndexOf("YourProcess.exe") != -1))
                proc.Attach();
        }

        internal static DTE2 GetCurrent()
        {
            var dte2 = (DTE2)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0"); // For VisualStudio 2013

            return dte2;
        }
```

Usage:

```
Attach(GetCurrent());
```